# Restart foreach loop if condition is satisfied on last iteration

Tags: php, foreach, do-while, continue

How do I restart a foreach loop when I reach the last index and some other condition?

The loop needs to run again, instead, it just stops.

```
foreach ($getUsers as $index => $user) {
    $userID = saveToDB($user, rand(1,1000));
    if($index == count($getUsers) && alreadyUsed($userID)) {
         reset($getUser);
         reset($index);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Simply use a while loop and get count of `$getUsers` and reset the index to 0 in an if condition something like this `$index == $count - 1 && alreadyUsed($userID)` else keep incrementing the index.

Comment: @Adi please do not post resolving advice as a comment -- this is how Stack Overflow pages become abandoned (and then when contributors do answer, they are not rewarded by the asker because the asker has vanished with the commented solution).

Comment: @ABigBird For indexed arrays, `$index` and `count($getUsers)` will never be equal because the count is 1 more than the highest index.  It would be great if you could set us up a [mcve] so that we could show you a better way to write your code.  `$index` is a key and therefore cannot be an array -- so `reset($index)` makes no sense.

Comment: @ABigBird Can you explain why you _think_ you need to restart the loop? I have no idea what problem you think you need to solve.  A foreach each will visit each element once. What is the challenge in your `saveToDB()` process? https://3v4l.org/Oqr1k7  Why can't the solution be as simple as https://3v4l.org/AQfI8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [reset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) function in PHP is used to reset the internal pointer of an array to its first element, but it doesn't impact the control flow of a foreach loop, you could achieve desired behaviour, like this:

```
$continueLoop = true;

while ($continueLoop) {
    foreach ($getUsers as $index => $user) {
        $userID = saveToDB($user, rand(1,1000));

        if ($index == count($getUsers) - 1 && alreadyUsed($userID)) {
            // If you reach the last user and the userID is already used,
            // continue the outer while loop
            continue 2;
        }
    }

    // If the end of the foreach loop is reached without restarting,
    // break out of the while loop
    $continueLoop = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand at all what `saveToDB()` and `alreadyUsed()` do, but you can re-visit the `foreach()` loop (which isn't affected by array pointers, so no resetting is needed) by using a post-test while loop.

```
do {
    foreach ($getUsers as $user) {
        $userID = saveToDB($user, rand(1, 1000));
    }
} while (isset($userID) && alreadyUsed($userID));
```

This way you don't need to use any clunky variables or any conditional controls in the loop body.

Because you only want to perform the check after the last iteration of the `foreach()` has had its chance to execute `saveToDB()`, you can verify that the `foreach()` loop has been entered (and therefore declared `$userID`) and then check if `alreadyUsed()` has returned a truthy result.

In other words, `isset($userID)` needs to be written in case `$getUsers` is empty.

I've even removed the `$index` variable because it is no longer needed.

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach ($getUsers as $index => $user) {
    $userID = saveToDB($user, rand(1,1000));
    if ($index == count($getUsers) - 1 && alreadyUsed($userID)) {
        continue;
    }
    // Code...
}
```

When the condition is met, the loop will skip the rest of the current iteration and start from the next iteration, thus restarting the loop.

Sorry google translate :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).